# Visual Studio - Xamarin - Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I hope you can help me, my codes are correct but the emulator just shows the title of the app. Also, when I wait to for it to display it says that XAML hot reload failed to initialize. Can somebody help me with this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQrTq.png)

I've tried restarting my laptop and all the basic troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to solve this:

- Try clean up and rebuild the entire project.
- Make sure you don't miss `InitializeComponent();` in the .cs file
- Make sure you don't accidentally have another file with the same class

Answer (score 0):

If XAML Hot Reload fails to initialize:

1.Update your Xamarin.Forms version.

2.Ensure you are on the latest version of the IDE.

3.Set your Android or iOS Linker settings to Don't Link in the project's build settings.

More detailed info about XAML Hot Reload for Xamarin.Forms, you can take a look:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/hot-reload